# How do I allow more than 10 connections to IIS on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, iis

How do I allow more than 10 connections to IIS on Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil set w3svc/MaxConnections 40
```

This should up the connection to 40 (which is the max as far as I know.)

Comment: +1 Your answer is easier and better.